# Triangles Question

Tags: geometry

In $\triangle ABC$, we have $AB = AC = 13$ and $BC = 10$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$ and $N$ be on $\overline{BC}$ such that $\overline{AN}$ is an altitude of $\triangle ABC$. If $\overline{AN}$ and $\overline{CM}$ intersect at $X$, then what is $AX$?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

$X$ is the centroid of $ABC$, hence $AX=\frac{2}{3}AN$. By the Pythagorean theorem $AN=12$, hence:
$$ AX=\color{red}{8}.$$